# Text control in WPF automatically scrolling its content if it does not fit in the available space

Tags: wpf, text, textbox, scroll

I'm looking for a text control that will continuosly horizontal scroll its content if it does not fit into the available space.

I really don't know where to start looking. Is there any control out there with similar capabilities our should I start one from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: you mean as a roller ?

Comment: Dani: I would preffer the text bouncing from one side to the other one but a roller could work if the bouncer is not available.